# How to clear elements from SimpleAdapter?

Tags: android, listview, simpleadapter

I am trying to fill the listview on a SET button.As i select the values spinner and according to list will fill. Problem i am facing is at many times i click on SET button it will add items to listview . [image]

```
   setButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
       for (int i = 0; i < DeviceID.size(); i++) 
       {

                //initialize row data
                for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
                    if (j == 0)
                        str = DATE.get(i);
                    else if (j == 1)
                        str = TIME.get(i);
                    else if (j == 2)
                        str = DeviceID.get(i);
                    else if (j == 3)
                        str = SMSTEXT.get(i);
                    map.put(columnTags[j], str);
                }
                mylistData.add(map);
            }

   final String[] columnTags = new String[]{"one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "lat", "log"};
    final int[] columnIds = new int[]{R.id.textView5, R.id.textView8, R.id.textView9,R.id.checkbox, R.id.textView10};
    arrayAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, mylistData, R.layout.location_locator_textview, columnTags, columnIds);

     listview.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
     arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
     }
    });
```

Comment: Post the code you tried.

Comment: you only posted initialization code. Post the code where you update your adapter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your list `mylistData` is a global variable. So, the old items are still in the list.

Either make it local inside the `onClick` method, or clear it in the first line of the `onClick` method. (Also the same case for `map`)

```
public void onClick(View view){
    mylistData.clear();
    map.clear();
    //your code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can call `listview.setAdapter(null);` before you set your items into listview

Comment: I tried, But not Working.Because my adapter always have value @hasbi

Comment: can you share set function and adapter/listview parts of your code

Comment: i added you can see this @ hasbi

Answer (score 0):

Try to modify the `list` of an element in your `adapter` and then call `notifyDataSetChanged()`.

It  would be easier if you post the code